# Yii App Reaches Memory Limit On Linux Server

Tags: php, memory, yii, limit, cpanel

I have a really strange problem and I dont know how to solve it. My application reaches memory limit from time to time and Internal server error 500 happens. I have limit of 570MB on shared hosting. I tried to debug my application and YiiDebug Toolbar shows that every page is consuming about 10-12MB of memory. I dont really get where is the problem. On my local wamp server, there are no problems.

Can anyone help me? At least tell me where to start looking for memory leaks because I dont see any obvious.
This is unpredictable problem, it does not happen on some particular request.
I already commented 'YII_DEBUG' line in index.php.

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '570MB');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got a lot of AR records, you might also look into the brand new [CActiveDataProviderIterator](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/pull/546) that just landed on master.  It's not part of a stable Yii release yet and there is little documentation (I'm helping work on that now actually).  But could be a place where you're hitting some memory limits.

And are you using GiiX by any change?  I've found it's fairly inefficient in some places, leading to the need to query more leanly ...

Comment: no, im not using giix.. i don't really know how much is a lot of AR records?
on frontpage I have CGridView with 3 pages (DataProvider is from AR).
i have 4 more pages, all of them get data from AR. 3 of them have about 20-30 records and one have 50-60 records.
Is that lot of AR records?

Comment: Doesn't sound too bad, and if you're using pagination, shouldn't be a huge deal. Are you loading up other relations as well? The Iterator class was aimed at 1000s of AR records being loaded it looked like

Comment: Can the problem be in .htaccess file? I have RewriteEngine On there to redirect http access to https.

Comment: Doubt it, I do something similar without issues.  Do you have the system email you with your errors when you have the problem?  Yii can have errors all logged / emailed to admins.  Might be the easiest way to track it down ...

Comment: Where can I set that errors are emailed to admins?

Can the problem be because I am not unseting variables after using it? I thought that PHP does that automaticaly.

Comment: See this section of the Yii guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#message-routing

Answer (score 0):

See the posting at - http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/15647-memory-usage/

A bit outdated but the points are still relevant.

If you can, use some kind of caching software to compliment the Active Record system.

If you are using Active Record, then ensure that the amount of models being loaded is not too much.

Debugging takes additional memory - if you do not need it disable it.

If the problem still persists consider moving from active record to DAO, but this can be messy.

What version of Yii are you using? and what is the number of typical visitors on your site?

Comment: thanks, I'll look that link.
I am using latest Yii version and my site is not really crowded. It is a small intranet for one association.